# Database structure for level packs, levels and level information

Tags: data-structure, databases, levels

I have a game which shall consist of several level packs (and also be extended by additional level packs). Each level pack should contain some levels. Each level will have its own level information.
How do I store this information? Do I use one big database, or should I split the information into several databases? (one database for one levelpack, or even one database for one level?)

EDIT:
To be more precise, I want to store the following level information:

- Several simple key-value pairs
- Some (primitive type) arrays
- An array-list (with informations like: x-, y-coordinates and an Integer)

This information should be stored for each level. I am planning for creating 10-20 levels. These levels shall be located in level packs. 
I need to get access to them dynamically (printing a level list with the level information an the display).

Comment: What do you mean by "database"? Do you mean a real Relational database, a NoSQL database, or just some file-format that you read (and I wish people would stop trying to call the latter "databases")?

Comment: yes i do mean a real relational (SQL-)database.

Comment: Telling us what you plan to store in these level files would help.

Comment: You should do more research on what databases are and how to design a relational DB. It makes no sense to have multiple databases for this.

Comment: i know how to work with databases, but i have no practical experience of how the structure shall look like (especially for this case) - that's why i am asking

Comment: Well, you could have level data stored in whatever format you want as binary data or text data. Have a "level"-table with id and data columns and have a "levelpack"-table, then look up on the internet how to do a one-to-many or many-to-many relationship. Assuming you have a need to fetch individual levels. If not, you could just have the levelpacks in an archive that user will have to unzip, but we dont know much of the usecase here.

Comment: @user1349812 Your question suggests that although you may have some experience working with databases, you do not have the experience to know how to design them well (or you would not be asking if you need multiple databases).

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're making an MMO or something so huge that you need it (and no, 10,000 elements doesn't cut it), you should not be using a relational database of any kind. Especially not for something as trivial as a list of stuff that goes in a level or series of levels. That's tremendous overkill.

Just use a file. An XML file if you must. It contains a list of files that are associated with each level. Or group of levels.

There is no need to go to the level of a relational DB.

Comment: Dear God, not XML. XML produces huge files that are not easy to understand.

Comment: @ashes999 I disagree XML is perfectly human readable when done properly, has a huge amount of tools to parse/manipulate it, and the file size difference is rarely going to be noticeable beside your art assets. Nothing so awful as to warrant devine intervention :)

Comment: I agree with all your points. But, there are better formats.